# Плевелы — единственное число и род

Tags: орфография, единственное-множественное-число, существительные, род

Плевелы
(Мат.13:25 ,27). Под означенным словом вообще разумеются все сорные травы, как то: куколь, дикий овес и другие, растущие среди пшеницы.
Отцы Церкви описывают плевелы как особое растение, несколько похожее на пшеницу, но вредное по своим семенам. Cв. Иоанн Златоуст пишет: плевелы с виду походят несколько на пшеницу, и, по словам св. Макария Египетского, они незаметны во множестве пшеницы; но хлеб, испеченный из пшеницы, неочищенной от семян плевел, производит вредное действие на желудок и голову, тяжкие обмороки и иногда смерть. Так как только самое тонкое зрение может открыть различие между пшеницею и плевелами, то их обыкновенно оставляют расти вместе до времени начала жатвы. Слуги, в притче Господа о плевелах, просили у своего господина дозволения исторгнуть плевелы, но он отвечал им: нет; чтобы, выбирая плевелы, вы не выдергали вместе с ними пшеницы, оставьте расти вместе то и другое до жатвы" (Мат.13:29 ,30).
Плевел или плевела? А может, "плевело" — по аналогии с семя?

Comment: Лучше поздно, чем никогда. Благодарю Вас, Аллазар (имя-то какое интересное!), за оценку ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В толковом словаре Д. Н. Ушакова:
**пле́вел**, -а, р. мн. ***-вел и -велов***, **м.** (книжн.).
1. Сорная трава, растущая среди хлебных злаков. || Название некоторых луговых и полевых трав из семейства злаков, отдельные виды которых являются сорными (бот.). *Льновый плевел* (сорняк льна). *Опьяняющий плевел* (сорняк в посевах яровых хлебов). *Многолетний плевел*.
2. ***перен., только мн.*** Что-нибудь вредное, дурное, портящее, засоряющее что-нибудь, преимущ. в заимствованном из Евангелия аллегорическом выражении: отделить плевелы от пшеницы (т. е. худое от хорошего, неиспорченного еще).

*И **пле́велов** зёрна в своей колыбели

Проснулись под ветром и вдаль полетели,

Смешались с толпа́ми осенних листов,

И гнили в объятиях мёртвых цветов.*
Перси Биши Шелли. Мимоза

*Насилу мы нашли могилу актёра Мушкина. Она осунулась, поросла **плевелом** и утеряла образ могилы…* (А. П. Чехов. На кладбище)

**Дополнение**
Стоит обратить внимание на рекомендации современных словарей:
мн. число — **пле́велы**; Р. п. мн. числа в первом значении (о растении) — **пле́велов**, во втором значении (переносном) — **пле́вел** (см. [орфографический словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%EF%EB%E5%E2%E5%EB)).